# Web page load issue intermittently and no html/js requests triggered except the bundles from Asp.net MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, dotless, system.web.optimization

We have an asp.net MVC application and facing an issue for a specific web page that fails to load initially for few times but loads subsequently.

I tried looking in the network tab for network activity and identified that whenever there is an issue on the loading page, there is one bundle request for LESS from the server which is followed by bundle response for JS files. After these responses, there is no further requests to load HTML files which are needed to render the web page.

Please give inputs on this.

Comment: Did you check the event log on the server? Sometimes .net will log in response to internal issues. I had a machine once where there was some sort of memory bug/.net core engine issue which intermittently threw errors. On another machine everything ran fine.

Comment: @Charleh Looks like there is nothing much in server logs. I was thinking, whenever there is a failure in page load, there is one extra request to bundle/less after which is there are no further page load or JS load requests. SO i am figuring its something related to dotless or system.web.optimization. But not sure what could be the exact issue.

Comment: could you share which iis feature you enabled? and did you face this issue before hosting in iis?

Comment: @JalpaPanchal Not sure but server team should have enabled general features. Nothing special. Its a new application and facing this issue with only a couple of pages in complete web application since it has been hosted initially.

Comment: check that .NET Extensibility 4.8,ASP.NET 4.8,ASP.NET, Static Content this feature is enabled. you could refer this [link](https://forums.iis.net/post/2152632.aspx) for more iis required feature list information.